# WP_Query on "property" in the options table

Tags: wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries, options

I'm quite new to WP and I hope this question isn't seen as too specific. It's not entirely bound to my little "pre story". I'd really like an answer to this question for future cases as well.

I get handed a project which uses WooCommerce and a plugin to that called [Product Vendors](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-vendors/).

The taxonomy for this plugin is called "shop_vendor". It has some extra data (vendor admins, commission and PayPal email address) that is saved in the options table. We then proceeded to add more fields (address, featured flag and a type (person or business)) to this taxonomy in the same manner.

We then made a API that can only get product information based on filter params. It uses code from the WooCommerce REST API, the query function can be found [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/api/class-wc-api-products.php#L463). To handle the other filters I have just added on more to the $query_args array. Here's how I managed to filter on the vendor slug.

```
if ( ! empty( $args['shop_vendor'] ) ) {
    $vendor_query = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'shop_vendor',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $args['shop_vendor']
    );
    array_push ( $query_args['tax_query'] , $vendor_query );
    unset($args['shop_vendor']);
}
```

Here's, after a small wall of text, where my problem shows up. I need to filter the products on the vendor type we added to the vendor. The rest of the filtering is done with a WP_Query. I can't figure out how to, it at all possible, incorporate data from the options table in a WP_Query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Ludvig

== Edit =============================================

So.. This question does NOT "primarily pertain to 3rd-party plugins". I was merely mentioning the plugin as a part of the "story" behind how I ran in to what is my actual problem.

The problem is, in a shorter version, that some of the data on which I want to filter resides in the options table shaped like this;

```
a:6:{
    s:6:"admins";
    a:1:{
        i:0;
        s:1:"1";
    }
    s:10:"commission";
    s:2:"50";
    s:12:"paypal_email";
    s:0:"";
    s:11:"is_featured";
    s:1:"1";
    s:4:"type";
    i:1;
    s:13:"ssn_or_org_no";
    s:10:"1234567890";
}
```

The option_name value in the options table is shop_vendor_[id] (where the id is the 184 in the SQL query below)

The WP_Query I have (without any of the optional filters added) is equal to this SQL question.

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
    AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (184) ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
    AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'instock') ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC;
```

What I want to know is how, if possible, can I add to this WP_Query such as if I had joined on the options table and then checked the "type" column.

Is there anything else I have to explain or did I do a better job of describing my conundrum this time around?

Regards, Ludvig

Comment: Howdy. Questions that primarily pertain to 3rd-party plugins are out of scope for this forum. Right now, it's hard to tell exactly where your question falls on that spectrum. If you can, please refocus your question on a WordPress development issue you're facing and not the plugins involved. Looking at your question, I think adding some additional code and background (what you've tried, what didn't work, what you need to happen, etc.) will help clarify your exact question.

Comment: There's no native relationship between options and any other table, and the data you've got is serialized php which is opaque to mysql, so there is no simple way to query on it.

Comment: OK Thanks for your comment @Milo. And if I would save the extra data as taxonomy meta according to [this article](http://www.codehooligans.com/2010/07/07/custom-meta-for-new-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/), the could someone kindly explain how I hook it in to the WP_Query so that I can query products with a vendor of type X? Or would it just be simpler to write my own normal SQL query?

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+serialized